# I request for help on how to come up with the dashboard in the image attached

Tags: codenameone

Dashboard Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fq9I.png

I kindly seek guidance on how to come up with that dashboard; how to generate those graphs, how to lay them exactly like that and how to size them like that.

Comment: Could you please tell us what have you already started to do and what are the exact problems? It would be best to create separate question for every specific issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I created the doughnut graph, I tried to put it in a container as it appears in the container and size the container but I failed. It just keeps appearing in the centre of my simulator screen

Comment: As you probably understood each one of those is a chart which you need to place within a BoxLayout Y container so they will be one on top of the other or in a TableLayout where you can force the height of each element to a percentage of the screen. If this doesn't work for you please write a question with the code you tried to achieve that, the original image and the result you got. We'll try to help you from that point.